# mysql join ON and AND to laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've been able to get the query result I need using the following raw sql:

```
select `person`.`id`, `full_name`, count(actions.user_id) as total
from `persons`
left join `actions`
on `actions`.`person_id` = `persons`.`id` 
and `actions`.`user_id` = $user
where `type` = 'mp' 
group by `persons`.`id`
```

But I haven't been able to get it working in eloquent yet.

Based on some similar answers, I'd tried functions within `->where()` or `leftJoin()`, but the `count` of each person's actions isn't yet being filtered by `$user`. As it stands:

```
$query = Person::leftJoin('actions', function($q) use ($user)
        {
            $q->on('actions.person_id', 'persons.id')
                ->where('actions.user_id', $user);
        })
        ->groupBy('persons.id')
        ->where('type', 'foo')
        //->where('actions.user_id', '=', $user)
        ->get(['persons.id', 'full_name', DB::raw('count(actions.id) as total')]);
```

I'm at least heading in *roughly* the right direction, right...?

If it's relevant, the `Persons.php` model has two `actions` relationships:

```
public function actions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Action');
}

public function actionsUser($id)
{
    return $this->hasMany('Action')->where('user_id', $id);
}
```

Comment: did you specify in your `Person.php` class that the table name is `persons`?? If not Laravel will try to make the query calling the plural of Person, in this case the table People.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I'm using the names in here as masking for what's actually being done, and I didn't realise Laravel is that clever!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, for reference, I solved it like so:

```
$query = Person::leftJoin('actions', function($q) use ($user)
        {
            $q->on('actions.person_id', '=', 'persons.id')
                ->where('actions.user_id', '=', "$user");
        })
        ->groupBy('persons.id')
        ->where('type', 'foo')
        ->get(['persons.id', 'full_name', DB::raw('count(actions.id) as total')]);
```

The `->where()` clause within `leftJoin`, oddly, needs the speech marks for the variable to be passed through the sql query correctly (likewise, '2' doesn't seem to work while "2" does).

Comment: Yes, you need to specify all 3 params for `on` and `where` called on the `JoinClause`. And for `"` - no need for that if you pass a variable.

Comment: If `$user` is an object with a `__toString()` method it could be that interpolating it into a string (in those double quotes like `"$user"`) is doing an implicit (string) cast which returns `2`. Hard to know without seeing the type of $user.

Answer (score 24):

I found that the `where` doesn't always work on the `leftJoin` clause

If in the future you get any trouble with it, I'd suggest you using this:

```
    $query = Person::leftJoin('actions', function($q) use ($user)
    {
        $q->on('actions.person_id', '=', 'persons.id')
            ->on('actions.user_id', '=', "$user");
    })
    ->groupBy('persons.id')
    ->where('type', 'foo')
    ->get(['persons.id', 'full_name', DB::raw('count(actions.id) as total')]);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Came to that conclusion myself as well. Using `->where` will force Eloquent to make a value parameter binding (e.g. `actions.user_id = ?`) query whereas using `->on` simply compares the SQL columns.

Comment: This works.  Unclear why this is nowhere to be found in the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 2):

**When laravel eloquent just start getting complex like this**

For more flexibility and readability I'll just use plain sql statement then hydrate the results.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT `person`.`id`,
        `full_name`,
        count(actions.user_id) AS total
    FROM `persons`
    LEFT JOIN `actions`
        ON `actions`.`person_id` = `persons`.`id` 
        AND `actions`.`user_id` = $user
    WHERE `type` = 'mp' 
    GROUP by `persons`.`id`
";

$query = Person::hydrate(
    DB::select( $sql )
);
```