# Full outer join table A and only records that existing table B with additional where clause

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables:

**officehour**

| weekday | open | close | doc_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 16:00 | 19:00 | 1 |
| Tuesday | 08:00 | 11:00 | 1 |
| Tuesday | 15:00 | 19:00 | 2 |
| Thursday | 16:00 | 19:00 | 1 |
| Friday | 08:00 | 10:00 | 1 |
| Friday | 15:00 | 19:00 | 2 |
| Saturday | 08:00 | 11:00 | 2 |

**closed**

| closed_date | open | close | closed | doc_id | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-23 | 16:00 | 17:00 | 0 | 2 | Interview |
| 2022-08-30 | null | null | 1 | 1 | Vacation |
| 2022-08-30 | 16:00 | 17:00 | 0 | 2 | Sleep In. |

I need all the records from officehour, so I thought I'd be using a left outer join and all the records from closed where the doc_id matches AND the weekday matches for the closed date if closed.

There will never be an instance of having a closed record where there isn't an officehour record.

How can I get the following using mysql (or eloquent)?

| weekday | open | close | doc_id | closed_date | open | close | closed | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 16:00 | 19:00 | 1 | null | null. | null. | null. | null. |
| Tuesday | 08:00 | 11:00 | 1 | 2022-08-30 | null | null | 1 | Vacation |
| Tuesday | 15:00 | 19:00 | 2 | 2022-08-23 | 16:00 | 17:00 | 0 | Interview |
| Tuesday | 15:00 | 19:00 | 2 | 2022-08-30 | 16:00 | 17:00 | 0 | Sleep In. |
| Thursday | 16:00 | 19:00 | 1 | null | null. | null. | null. | null. |
| Friday | 08:00 | 10:00 | 1 | null | null. | null. | null. | null. |
| Friday | 15:00 | 19:00 | 2 | null | null. | null. | null. | null. |
| Saturday | 08:00 | 11:00 | 2 | null | null. | null. | null. | null. |

I've tried a few things, but this is my most recent query:

```
$hours = DB::select("SELECT * from officehour a FULL OUTER JOIN closed b ON a.doc_id = b.doc_id WHERE date_format(b.closed_date,'W%') = a.weekday");
dd($hours);
```

I get the following error when I try to add a where clause:
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN closed b ON a.doc_id = b.doc_id WHERE date_format(closed_d' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT * from officehour a FULL OUTER JOIN closed b ON a.doc_id = b.doc_id WHERE date_format(b.closed_date,'W%') = weekday)`

I have also tried:
`DB::select("SELECT * from officehour a FULL OUTER JOIN closed b ON a.doc_id = b.doc_id WHERE date_format(b.closed_date,'W%') = a.weekday");`

I also read something that said I'm having syntax errors cause it doesn't like full outer joins, so I tried this:

```
$second = DB::table('closed')
            ->rightJoin('officehour', 'officehour.doctor_id', '=', 'closed.doctor_id');

$first = DB::table('officehour')
    ->leftJoin('closed', 'officehour.doctor_id', '=', 'closed.doctor_id')
    ->unionAll($second)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, a union of left join and right join (use regular union, not union all) is the workaround to do a full outer join in MySQL. MySQL has had this feature request since 2006, but has never implemented it: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18003

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help] Please indent code reasonably.

Comment: No full join in MySQL. That's a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Easy to say, but I thought I gave enough information or I wouldn't have posted.  Full join doesn't work in MySQL I guess is the answer I'm looking for, unless someone can explain how to take the sample data from table 1 and table 2 and turn it into table 3.  :(

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please edit to 1 question with all & only what it needs, per my 1st comment. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join and the condition for the date in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM officehour o LEFT JOIN closed c 
ON o.doc_id = c.doc_id AND date_format(c.closed_date,'%W') = o.weekday;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0e81a5cc3dfe8b4c433a74a066da2ac4).

Comment: THANK YOU!  I knew I wasn't a complete idiot, and that I gave enough information to solve the problem.  You rock, forpas!  I started with a left join but had it in the where section and got lost and confused from there.

Comment: And I was able to use eloquent so it can be quickly filtered on the fly.  :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460945/mysql-join-on-and-and-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

1. You never told SQL to open the table officehour as 'a'
2. You never told SQL to open the table closed as 'b'

Here is the statement.

```
$hours = DB::select("SELECT * FROM officehour AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN closed AS b ON a.doc_id = b.doc_id WHERE date_format(b.closed_date,'W%') = a.weekday");
dd($hours);
```

Comment: Apparently this won't work either cause full joins won't work in MySQL (learned that today at least).  I sure do appreciate you understanding what I'm trying to do, though, and offering an possible solution.

Comment: Then perhaps this will.